# Remove-Variable - Cannot find a variable with the name

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I have a powershell script that with the following `hashtable`

```
[HashTable]$folder_and_prefix = @{}
```

After a certain point in my script I no longer need that `hashtable`, I tried doing:

`Remove-Variable $folder_and_prefix`

but I get the following error:

> Remove-Variable : Cannot find a variable with the name
>   'System.Collections.Hashtable'

Is it possible to remove a hastable that I no longer need?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a common mistake. `Remove-Variable` is taking the *name of the variable* (a `[String]`), and by referencing the variable itself (with a dollar sign `$`) you are passing the *value*. Remove the dollar sign and that's all you need:

```
Remove-Variable folder_and_prefix
```

Further, it takes an array of names, so you can do:

```
$var1 = 5
$var2 = 'Hello'
$var3 = @{}

Remove-Variable var1,var2,var3
```

And it accepts wildcards:

```
Remove-Variable var*
```

The wildcard acceptance is also true for `Set-Variable`, `Get-Variable`, and `Clear-Variable` (`New-Variable` is the exception).

Comment: The Microsoft help page could really highlight this information. It is clear now, but without your hint I would have not come up to that. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by others, don't use the dollar sign ($) when referring to the variable itself. Additionally, I always check to see if variable exists (before attempting to delete it) using conditional statement as below:

```
if (Test-Path variable:myVar) {Remove-Variable myVar}  #Delete only if local variable exists.
[int]$myVar = 5;
```

You can also check your variable's existence in a specific Scopes, such as, for Global scope:

```
if (Test-Path variable:global:myVar) {Remove-Variable myVar –Scope Global}
```

You can even check Environment variables as below:

```
if (Test-Path env:ComputerName) {"do something with $env:ComputerName."}
```

HTH